# Can I nest headers in a stackview using Clarity

Tags: vmware-clarity, stackview

In Clarity 2, we used the following code to generate a stack view with nested block headers.

```
<clr-stack-view>
    <clr-stack-block [clrSbExpanded]="true">
        <clr-stack-label>Leases</clr-stack-label>
        <clr-stack-block [clrSbExpanded]="true">
            <clr-stack-label>vApp leases</clr-stack-label>
            <clr-stack-content></clr-stack-content>
            <clr-stack-block>
                <clr-stack-label>Runtime expiry action</clr-stack-label>
                <clr-stack-content>Never expires</clr-stack-content>
            </clr-stack-block>
            <clr-stack-block>
                <clr-stack-label>Runtime Expiry Action</clr-stack-label>
                <clr-stack-content>Content</clr-stack-content>
            </clr-stack-block>
        </clr-stack-block>
    </clr-stack-block>
</clr-stack-view>
```

After upgrading to Clarity 3, I'm getting a glitch on my sub header where the right part of it is white instead of the background color.

[image: Glitch on sub header]

This seems to be because of the following CSS rule. I can probably workaround it...

```
.stack-view .stack-children .stack-block-label, .stack-view .stack-children .stack-block-content {
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: var(--clr-stack-view-stack-children-stack-block-label-and-content-bg-color, white);
}
```

The question is whether this a bug? Or was I just using unsupported behavior in Clarity 2? You can [play with it here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-view-nested-header?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say whether it's a bug, but the following CSS override fixes it.

```
.stack-view .stack-children .stack-block-content {
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

Moreover, if I remove that style declaration completely (from dev tools), everything seems to work fine, so it seems like that rule was left there by mistake to try to make sure the `clr-stack-content|label` was white in the body. Heck if I know...

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-view-nested-header-fixed?file=src%2Findex.html

Comment: This should be the fix for the workaround. It may be a regression but we would need to investigate more. There was a change to the nested stack-block-component last year that looks like it makes nested stack-content components theme-able. 

This should be the answer.

Comment: Is there any other fix for this? I am facing a similar issue while nesting `clr-stack-block` and adding the CSS did not help.

Comment: @nomadev95 Sounds like a separate question. May be related but it's different. Please ask it separately so it can be more helpful to others.